# How do I tell if an optional parameter exists or not in python

Tags: python, class, boolean

```
class Dimensional:
    def __init__(self, gravity, l=0, m=0, t=0):
        assert type(l) == int
        assert type(m) == int
        assert type(t) == int

        self.gravity = gravity
        self.l = l
        self.m = m
        self.t = t
```

I'm trying to define a `__bool__` method that returns True for any non-zero value
What I did:

```
def __bool__(self): 
    g = self.gravity
    _l = self.l
    _m = self.m
    _t = self.t
    if not self.gravity:
        g += 1
    if not self.l:
        _l += 1
    if not self.m:
        _m += 1
    if not self.t:
        _t += 1

    if g != 0 and _l != 0 and _m != 0 and _t != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: assert is not a good way to control the flow of your application. You may also find `any` useful

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in that `__bool__`. Do you mean just `return any(self.gravity, self.l, self.m, self.t)`?

Comment: What does this have to do with optional parameters, or determining whether they were specified by the user?

Comment: To avoid all those `assert` commands...  If `l`, `m`, and `t` must be integer values, you could throw an exception if any argument doesn't equal to its own integer value (`if int(m) != m: raise ValueError('Meaningful error message.')`), and then assign the each integer value to the object's field (`self.m = int(m)`).

Answer (score 0):

Just return the boolean conversion of an `or` expression on all the attributes:

```
def __bool__(self): 
    return bool(self.gravity or self.l or self.m or self.t)
```

If any of these values is not 0, `bool()` will produce `True`, otherwise it'll produce `False`.

Your code would **always** return True, regardless; for any field that's `0` you *incremented* your variable; so your 4 local variables all end up at non-zero, guaranteed.

Demo with the above method:

```
>>> bool(Dimensional(0,1,1,1))
True
>>> bool(Dimensional(0,0,0,0))
False
```

Note that if you are using Python 2, you need to name the method [`__nonzero__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) instead; `__bool__` is the Python 3 name.

Comment: Thanks! but it still doesn't pass this: bool(Dim(0,1,1,1))

Comment: @Frog_Luan: `bool(Dimensional(0,1,1,1))` produces `True`, because there are three non-zero values. Only `bool(Dimensional(0,0,0,0))` would produce `False`.

Comment: @Frog_Luan: you *are* using Python 3, right? On Python 2 there is no `__bool__` method; name it [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) instead.